# Enabling Toolset v110 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

How can I add the v110 Toolset to my Visual Studio 2015 Community Project? I can't select it in the Project preferences...

Comment: That can only work if you had VS2012 installed.

Comment: Had? I'm on a new machine, where VS2012 wasn't installed, I installed 2015 directly. But I have access to 2012. So does this mean I need to install 2012 in addition to 2015?